# Accessing Highcharts.Point with webpack and import

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, highcharts

I am having trouble accessing some functionality of Highcharts when using webpack to bundle my code/dependencies.

When I try to extend Highcharts like this:

```
import * as HC from "highcharts";

HC.Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function () {
    return undefined;
};

console.log("Hello World!");
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Pointer' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:1)
    at i (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
    at bundle.js:1
```

All other functionality of Highcharts works without problems, but the above is not possible.

Without webpack it works, but I want to bundle my libraries.

Comment: Have you tried debugging/logging the `HC` object to see how it looks like?

Comment: I think it should be HC.Pointer, without additional Highcharts prop - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mgcsnz?file=index.js